How to dynamically reply/promt to back to user in based on input in AWS Lex-Bot
I am creating a bot which will ask a user about the appointment date, and if apointment is not available on that day/date then the lex will respond back that sorry no appointment available on this day, please choose another day. Here is the scnario:
Lex bot “today is Friday, April 19 . What day would you like to have your appointment?”

Caller replies “Thursday  May 16th” (or 16th of May, 5/16 or May the 16th, etc.)(lets on May 16th no appoitment available)

Lex bot “I’m sorry, I do not have availability on that day. Can you please try another day?”

Caller replies “Wednesday, May 1st” (or 1st of May, 5/1 or May 1st, etc.)
LexBot "thanks for choosing this day"

and the bot will continue the conversation or moving to next intent or slot.
So how can I dynamically reply  back to customer/caller/user based on its input?
thanks in advance team.
I tried to handle that in the lexbot but unable to do that.

By dynamic, I'm understanding you to mean that you want the bot to respond to the user based on whether or not an appointment is available on the user's chosen date. So, either the bot must continue with the booking or request the user to select another date.
In AWS Lex you as the developer are responsible for managing how the bot responds. In your example, you need to integrate Lex with a Lambda function.
The Lambda function will be responsible for taking the user's input e.g.: the desired appointment date; performing the necessary business logic (i.e.: checking the calendar to see if the date is available), and then responding to the user accordingly.
You can control the flow of the conversation by using the Lambda function to determine what the next action is.
You can read more about this in the AWS Lex Developer Guide.
